# How to add country drop down menu to the user profile?

Tags: users, user-meta, dropdown

I've added this code snippet to my `functions.php`

```
function my_new_contactmethods( $contactmethods ) {  
    $contactmethods['country'] = 'country';
    return $contactmethods;
}
add_filter('user_contactmethods','my_new_contactmethods',10,1);
```

It works perfactly as I wanted. It show an extra field to fill up user country on user backend profile.

But it just a text field. Actually I want to show this field as a drop down menu which has all the countries.

How can I modify this code to get a country list dropdown menu ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
/* Save selected data */
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_user_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_user_fields' );

function save_user_fields( $user_id ) {

if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
    return false;

update_usermeta( $user_id, 'country', $_POST['country'] );
}

add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'Add_user_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'Add_user_fields' );

function Add_user_fields( $user ) {

?>

<h3>Additional Field</h3>
<table class="form-table">       

    <tr>
        <th><label for="dropdown">Select field</label></th>
        <td>
            <?php 
            //get dropdown saved value
            $selected = get_the_author_meta( 'country', $user->ID ); 
            ?>
            <select name="country" id="country">
                <option value="Argentina" <?php echo ($selected == "Argentina")?  'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Argentina</option>
                <option value="Belgium" <?php echo ($selected == "Belgium")?  'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Belgium</option>
                <option value="countryX" <?php echo ($selected == "countryX")?  'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>country X</option>
            </select>
            <span class="description">Select the above</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Hope this does your job.

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet Shreyo. Now I see the country dropdown list at the user profile. but it is not saved when I change the country. Eg: from the above list if I select `Belgium` and press the button `Update Profile` then again I see `Argentina` as default. Seems it is not get saved when we click `Update Profile` button. do we have to something else to get it saved?

Comment: I will check if i missed any code. It's a working code.

Comment: @RiffazStarr, update this section:

update_usermeta( $user_id, 'country', $_POST['country'] );

updated the code too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update.. works like a charm.. How can I move this drop down list to `contact info` section where wordpress already has `email` and `website`??